# Docker multiple same port issue

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I am currently working on two inter related ASP.NET Core WebAPI services (Service1 & Service2) in a solution. Both are having docker files and exposing port 80.

Service1 is an independent service and required to be called from Service2. I have given both docker-compose.yml and docker-compose.override.yml.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

    services:
      services1:
        image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}services1
        network_mode: bridge
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Services1/Dockerfile
        ports:
         - "501:80"

      services2:
        image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}services2
        network_mode: bridge
        build:
          context: .
          Services2/Dockerfile
        ports:
         - "502:80"
```

**docker-compose.override.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  services1:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Services1/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "1001:80"

  services2:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Services2/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - SERVICE1=http://localhost:1001
      ports:
      - "1002:80"
```

When i call http://localhost:1001 from http://localhost:1002 with **network_mode: bridge**, I am getting the below exception.

> {System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Cannot assign requested address
>   ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Cannot assign requested address

when i change the network_mode to host ( **network_mode:host** ), i am getting the below exception.

> System.IO.IOException: 'Failed to bind to address http://[::]:80:
>   address already in use.'

So please let me know how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should stick with the default bridge mode (by removing `network_mode: bridge`) and change

```
  - SERVICE1=http://localhost:1001
```

to

```
  - SERVICE1=http://services1:80 # services1 will be resolved by docker
```

Because service1 and service2 are on separate containers, so there is no opened port 1001 on the container of service2.

Comment: Needs to be the internal port number (`http://services1:80/`, or even just `http://services1/` since that's the default HTTP port).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried both options but now i am getting the exception as {System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No such device or address ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such device or address

Answer (score 0):

From internal you can use container name instead of host and port (actually it's more practical), you can find your container name by typing `docker ps` in your terminal.

e.g. if you call service 1 from service 2 use http://asp_project_service1

Comment: Docker Compose sets up network aliases for the block names too, so you don't need to manually look up the container name it constructs.  `http://services1` should work here because that's what the block is named.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried both options but now i am getting the exception as {System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No such device or address ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such device or address