# .netcore microservices on Docker System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, docker-compose, identityserver4

I have three services, one is my local Identity Service (IS), the other two are regular .netcore 2.2 webapis.
I use IS as an authentication middleware and the two services need to authenticate against IS.
Everything runs smoothly when I host my apps on IIS for example.
When I try to do the same thing with docker and docker compose thing are not working anymore and I have the following error.

> Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden]'. ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is hidden]'. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Cannot assign requested address ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Cannot assign requested address

I am pasting the docker compose here:

```
services:
  management:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}management
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/Management/Dockerfile
    depends_on: 
      - auth.service

  auth.service:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}authservice
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/Authorization/Auth.Service/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro

  management2:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}management2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/Management2/Dockerfile
    depends_on: 
      - auth.service
```

and docker-compose.override.yml

```
version: "3.4"

services:
 management:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - auth.service=http://auth.service:80
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://0.0.0.0:80
    ports:
      - "58101:80"

  auth.service:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://0.0.0.0:80
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=5000

    ports:
      - "5001:80"
      - "5000:443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro

  management2:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - auth.service=http://auth.service:80
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://0.0.0.0:80

    ports:
      - "58102:80"
```

I tried doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54103725/docker-multiple-same-port-issue) and specifying in my authentication bearer options the authority as being the environment variable auth.service. Did not work.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY  Infrastructure Infrastructure
COPY  Authorization Authorization
COPY  Users Users

RUN dotnet restore "Authorization/Auth.Service/Auth.Service.csproj"

WORKDIR /src/Authorization/Auth.Service
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Auth.Service.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
RUN ls -ltr /app
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Auth.Service.dll"]
```

The rest is pretty similar. Only the names differ. It problem is that it cannot reach the well-known inside docker. If make a request on browser for the well-known, all nice and dandy. Inter-service, does not work, but again only on local machine in development.

Comment: pls share at least one `Dockerfile`? I've had some surprises with .NET Core custom `Dockerfile` that makes it very tricky to debug.

Answer (score 0):

When using IdentityServer on docker, you should be aware about https certificate, your services couldn't validate https certificate.

> Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden]'. ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804:

If you try to fetch IdentityServer configurations, you wont be able.
call this address and see the result:
https://auth.service/.well-known/openid-configuration

Comment: That is the things: the well known works. It works when running only the IS on docker. It does not work when using docker compose and the other services try to interact with IS. It works on a different environment too. Only on localhost it does not work.

Comment: you need to validate your certificate on any client how is calling IS, invalid certificate is a common issue in docker environment. set PII to true and see more details.